# Capybara Ambiguous

Tags: rspec, capybara, ambiguous

Hey guys I have this beautiful piece of code here, and what I trying to do is within specs to click the submit button  with value "Personal data change erstellen". Only problem is, I have like 5 other submit buttons with the same value, and I am trying to cover all this with in a method. Does anyone have a suggestion how to make it running, the Ambiguous error is killing me. Please see the code below.

```
      <legend>Handynummer</legend>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="banking_personal_data_change_value_adr_mobile">Adr mobile</label>
          <input class="form-control" value="49160002774531" name="banking_personal_data_change_value[adr_mobile]" id="banking_personal_data_change_value_adr_mobile" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="banking_personal_data_change[send_email]" value="0" type="hidden"><input value="1" checked="checked" name="banking_personal_data_change[send_email]" id="banking_personal_data_change_send_email" type="checkbox">
          <label for="banking_personal_data_change_send_email">E-Mail an den Kunden</label>
        </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <input name="commit" value="Personal data change erstellen" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      </div>
```

Comment: You could give each of those 5 buttons a unique id and then find it based on this id as opposed to finding it based on the value. Alternatively, give an id to the div/section that holds each of the 5 form groups and then use `within` to find the specific button.

Comment: @JanKlimo that solution definitely crossed my mind, only thing is, it is not my code, I am only hired to test its functionality, thats why I am desperately asking for help

Comment: Show enough html so we can see another instance of the "Personal data change erstellen" and advise you on which node you can use to scope the correct button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show enough HTML for us to see one of the other buttons and determine what the exact scoping is, but seeing that you're using a `legend` tag, I assume you have at least a `fieldset` around each button.  With that you should be able to scope to the fieldset (which I assume have unique legends) with something like

```
within_fieldset('Handynummer') do
  click_button('Personal data change erstellen')
end
```

or in one line

```
find(:fieldset, 'Handynummber').click_button('Personal data change erstellen')
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWalpole this solves a huge number of my problems

Answer (score 0):

Its fragile but you can use XPath to find the nth element

`(//input[@value="Personal data change erstellen"])[5]`

or something similar.